# C++ How do I delete a certan character in a string?

Tags: c++

Hello so I'm basically trying to do something like this.

```
PrintOpt("Hello | I | Am | Awesome");
```

and in my PrintOpt code

```
void PrintOpt(char* Text){
     if(!strcmp(Text, " | ")){
           Text = "\n";
     }
     printf(Text);
}
```

I would like it to print out like this

```
Hello
I
Am
Awesome
(On a new line)
```

But when I do this it doesn't print out anything. Does anyone know why this isn't working? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want every word on its own line? I.e. every instance of `|` is replaced with `\n`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I tried everything dude :/

Comment: That sounds more like *replacing* than *deleting*.

Comment: Why are you using C-style strings in a C++ program? You're likely just to get a big pile of answers saying "use std::string".

Comment: Dude, this is C code, not C++.  I would suggest taking a step back and reading up on string and pointers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a beginner at this. I don't really know the difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Right now you're passing the address of a string literal. Attempting to modify the content of that string literal will give undefined behavior, so most of the advice about *how* to do this will almost inevitably fail until/unless you pass something that can be modified safely.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `std::string` replace method

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should not pass string literal "" as `char *` and especially try to modify that data. Use `std::string` instead:

```
void PrintOpt(std::string Text){
     while( true ) {
         size_t pos = Text.find( " | " );
         if( pos == std::string::npos ) break;
         Text = Text.replace( pos, 3, "\n" );
     }
     std::cout << Text;
     // or printf(Text.c_str()); if you insist on printf()
}
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I was about to post. Although I did the `find` and check against `npos` in the `while` condition.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement "if(!strcmp(Text, " | ")) you get a false. Then you make the variable Text take the value "\n" and you print it (\n is the equivalent of a new line). I guess that's why it doesn't work as expected.

To replace characters you could use the function std::replace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use strcmp on the every character of string and not all of it at once.